# Exception starting filter action - unable to load configuration - java.net.UnknownHostException: struts.apache.org

Tags: java, xml, configuration, struts2

I have my internet connection working,
required jars are there in `classpath` as well,
and the versions of jars are matching. Need to know where I went wrong

```
Method: connect
Line: 177 - java/net/PlainSocketImpl.java:177:-1
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:360)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:403)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:69)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:48)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:277)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:382)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4649)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5305)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1585)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: Unable to load jar:file:/C:/Users/xxx/Documents/Test/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Mock/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.16.jar!/struts-default.xml - Class: java.net.PlainSocketImpl
File: PlainSocketImpl.java
Method: connect
Line: 177 - java/net/PlainSocketImpl.java:177:-1
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:890)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadDocuments(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:144)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.init(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:111)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:164)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:55)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: struts.apache.org - Class: java.net.PlainSocketImpl
File: PlainSocketImpl.java
Method: connect
Line: 177 - java/net/PlainSocketImpl.java:177:-1
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper.parse(DomHelper.java:115)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:885)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: struts.apache.org
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:177)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:163)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:394)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:529)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:233)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:306)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:323)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:975)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:916)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:841)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1177)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:677)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1315)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1282)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(XMLDTDScannerImpl.java:283)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1194)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1090)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1003)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:395)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper.parse(DomHelper.java:113)
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: struts.apache.org at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:177) at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)   but i have internet connection working

Comment: Don't post code in comments. Edit question, add full stacktrace, source code where the exception is occured. Other details you might think is relevant to the question and ofcourse the question itself. Without it your question is not valid on SO.

Comment: Unable to help with the Question. - Class: java.stackoverflow.UnexplainedQuestionError cause : question needs to be properly explained

Comment: added the complete stacktrace

Comment: I think `Unable to load jar:file:/C:/Users/xxx/Documents/.../struts2-core-2.3.16.jar` is key here. Check the jar file exists and is readable.

Answer (score 0):

When Struts2 application starts it loads default configuration from the core jar library. The default configuration file is `WEB-INF/lib/struts2-core-2.3.16.jar!/struts-default.xml`. It is a XML document which has a doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">
```

When the document is parsed it downloads a DTD specified by the URL. But `java.net.UnknownHostException` occurred to resolve hostname `struts.apache.org`. The exception indicates that the IP address of a host could not be determined.